# Unable to sum contents of .tiff files with conditional statement

Tags: python

Context:

I am attempting to sum .tiff files containing monthly evapotranspiration per year (e.g. sum all twelve months for 2007) to get an annual total evapotranspiration. However, the "if in" (see code) statement does not seem to filter for only the year 2007, causing all .tiff files for all years in the specified directory to be summed.

Question:

How can I make sure only the .tiff files are summed according to a specific year (in this example 2007)?

```
def pathList (d): # d is the path to the specified directory
   
   sum_array = np.zeros((2200, 2800)) # creating empty array in which to sum monthly evap. values
   nmlist = [] # creates an empty list object in which to store the names of the .tiff files
   count = 0 # creating variable to store index of files in directory

   for item in os.scandir(d): # iterating through directory contents
     
            nmlist.append(item.name) # preparing name list of .tiff files to use in "if in" statement (see below)

            tif_file = gdal.Open(pthlist[count]) # reading .tiff via gdal
            tif_band = tif_file.GetRasterBand(1) # reading first band
            tif_arr = tif_band.ReadAsArray() # converting to numpy array
            
            if "2007" in nmlist[count]: # does the name of the file contain a specific year (e.g. 2007)?
                sum_array = sum_array + tif_arr # summing monthly evap. values
       
            count += 1 # tracking index of files in directory

   return sum_array
```

See [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJS1B.png) for sample of names of .tiff files.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide sample of the data you have?

Comment: Give result of: print(item) after for loop, then print(item.name) right below the .append and finally look for "2017" in nmlist[count] doesn't makes sense. But without data, hard to guess,

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin, I added a link (via edit) to the names of the .tiff files. Is this enough, or do you want to look at an actual file?

Many thanks for helping!